# Añadir filas a Exceljs con React

Tags: json, nodejs, reactjs

Comunidad, saludos.
Soy bastante novata en React y Nodejs. Estoy realizando una app para exportar un JSON a Excel usando ExcelJS. El JSON está anidado y lo recupero así:

```
const objectsFromCols = () =>{
    const valuesToExport=[];
    rutas.forEach((ruta) => {
        let rutaExport={
            Ruta:ruta.label,
            Derrotero:ruta.value.descripcion,
            Inicio:ruta.value.inicio,
            Fin:ruta.value.fin,
            Ciudad:ciudad.nombre
        }
        valuesToExport.push(rutaExport);
    });
    return valuesToExport;
}
```

Y utilizo lo siguiente para llenar el Excel, tomado del siguiente repositorio 
[getting-started-with-exceljs](https://github.com/brcline/getting-started-with-exceljs/blob/master/index.js#L99)  :

```
    rutas.forEach((e, index) => {
     // row 1 is the header.
    const rowIndex = index + 2

    worksheet.addRow({
        ...e
        })
    });
```

Sin embargo, al momento de guardar el Excel, sólo me imprime los headers. ¿Alguien podría ayudarme con eso? Saludos y gracias de antemano.

Comment: A ver si te entiendo... Tu función `objectsFromCols` crea las `rows` que luego vas a insertar con `worksheet.addRow()`? Si es así, en algún momento estás haciendo `rutas = objectsFromCols()` para luego utilizar el  `rutas.forEach()` con los valores actualizados. Tal vez si compartes un poco m[as de tu código podría entender mejor.

Comment: La función {objectsFromCols} "desanida" el arreglo que estoy utilizando que es un json con un json dentro.

Comment: Eso lo entiendo, pero ¿Qué haces con el valor de retorno de tu función? A lo que entiendo usas la función para preparar los datos para ser convertidos a Excel, pero, ¿A la hora de crear el elemento de Excel haces referencia al JSON original no procesado?

Answer (score 1):

Viendo tu función y orientado a lo que explico en el comentario... Y si haces:

```
objectsFromCols().forEach((e, index) => {
    worksheet.addRow({
        ...e
        })
    });
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. No usé un forEach sino un for y descubrí que el problema es que estaba usando un nombre de variable que generaba ambigüedad. for(let i=0; i<rutasRows.length; i++)
            {
                const rowValues=[];

                rowValues[1]=(rutasRows[i]['Ruta']);
                rowValues[2]=(rutasRows[i]['Derrotero']);
                rowValues[3]=(rutasRows[i]['Inicio']);
                rowValues[4]=(rutasRows[i]['Fin']);
                rowValues[5]=(rutasRows[i]['Ciudad']);

                worksheet.addRow(rowValues);
            }

Comment: Oh ya veo, me alegra que se haya resuelto.